# Calling Direct Method and Handling Results from Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I am working on a simple IoT application that needs to be able to take sensor measurements on demand. I am using a serverless architecture where a simple button click on a static site triggers an Azure function. This function should invoke a direct method on a given IoT device and store the results in Cosmos DB. However, when this function executes (it executes successfully) the callback function for invokeDeviceMethod never executes. Instead, context.log("Somehow I got here without a callback") is logged and the function returns 200 success. The line just inside the if statement that logs req.query.method and req.query.device shows the expected values for both of those parameters. My device never receives the request to invoke the method and as such the callback is never executed. What am I missing in order to invoke a given method from an Azure function? I don't get any errors when running this as a function and calling the direct method from the Azure portal using the 'direct method' button on the device page works well. Thank you in advance for any assistance!

My azure function code is below.

```
'use strict';

const https = require('https');

var Client = require('azure-iothub').Client
//var Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
var conn_str = "<CONNECTION_STRING>"


module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    //context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function POSTMeasure processed a request.');

    if (req.query.method && req.query.device) {

        context.log("Direct Method Invocation! Calling "+req.query.method + " on " + req.query.device)

        var methodParams = {
            methodName: req.query.method,
            payload: {},
            connectTimeoutInSeconds: 15,
            responseTimeoutInSeconds: 15
        };

        context.log(methodParams);

        var client = Client.fromConnectionString(conn_str)

        client.invokeDeviceMethod(req.query.device, methodParams, function(err, result) {
            context.log("IN CALLBACK");
            if (err) {
                context.log("Direct method error: "+err.message);
                context.res = {
                    status: 500, /* Defaults to 200 */
                    body: "Failed " + req.query.method + " on " + req.query.device
                };
            } else {
                context.log("Successfully invoked the device to read dht11.");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
                context.res = {
                    // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
                    body: "Suceeded " + req.query.method + " on " + req.query.device
                };
            }
        });

        context.log("Somehow I got here without a callback");

    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a method and device on the query string"
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the function you pass to invokeDeviceMethod is not going to be executed until the call is complete. It is essentially a callback function to provide the result. Having called invokeDeviceMethod function JavaScript will execute the next line which is the "Somehow I got here...". You will need to modify your code to wait for the invokeDeviceMethod to complete and execute your callback. Now I'm no JavaScript programmer but you could, for example, wrap the call in a promise and wait on it. That way your function will delay until the call is finished. Primitive example of how you might do this:

```js
// Target function to wrap in promise for demonstration purposes
function test(callback)
{
    setTimeout(() => { callback(null, 'good') }, 4000);
}

// Wraps test in a promise
function testPromise()
{
    var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        test((err, result) => 
        {
            if (err)
            {
                reject(err);
            }
            else
            {
                resolve('good');
            }
        });
    });

    return p;
}

// Will not advance until the wrapped function has completed
testPromise()    
.then((result) => { console.log(result) })
.catch(() => { console.log("failed"); } )
```

Comment: Thank you Mark! For some reason I thought the fact that this was an async function in Azure, that handled waiting for the response. Turns out, it does just the opposite! I needed to remove the 'async' and control the flow myself within the function as you suggested.